# Exception while parsing metadata in BreezeJS client

Tags: entity-framework, enums, metadata, breeze

**Prequel and version info:**

BreezeJS client version: 1.5.2

Metadata generated on custom server via design-time EntityFramework model (6.1.2)

BreezeLabs EdmBuilder (1.0.5)

Had problems generating metadata also which can be read here:
[How to generate valid metadata from EF DBContext via EdmBuilder for OData v3/BreezeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077699/how-to-generate-valid-metadata-from-ef-dbcontext-via-edmbuilder-for-odata-v3-bre)

---

**Question/Problem:**

Now the breeze client is throwing an error while interpreting the metadata.

```
Unable to process returned metadata: A nonnullable DataProperty cannot have a null defaultValue. Name: MySuperDuperEnum
```

The exception occurs in `breeze.debug.js at line 7110 - function parseCsdlSimpleProperty(parentType, csdlProperty, keyNamesOnServer)`.

Whats going wrong here? Do I have wrong metadata?

Here is the metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="ODataMetaDataGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">

            <EntityType Name="MyObject" p5:ClrType="GreatPersistencyNamespace.Model.GreatStuff.MyObject, BreezeEval, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" xmlns:p5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
                </Key>
                <Property Name="ID" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Int32" p7:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" xmlns:p7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation"/>
                <Property FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max" Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true"/>
                <Property Name="IsActive" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
                <Property Name="IsGreat" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>
                <Property FixedLength="false" MaxLength="Max" Name="Description" Type="Edm.String" Unicode="true"/>
                <Property Name="Address" Nullable="false" Type="ODataMetaDataGenerator.Address"/>
                <Property Name="BehaviourType" Nullable="false" Type="ODataMetaDataGenerator.BehaviourType"/>
            </EntityType>

            <EnumType Name="BehaviourType" UnderlyingType="Edm.Byte" p5:ClrType="GreatPersistencyNamespace.Model.GreatStuff.BehaviourType, BreezeEval, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" xmlns:p5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation">
                    <Member Name="RUDE" Value="1"/>
                    <Member Name="KIND" Value="2"/>
                    <Member Name="UNKNOWN" Value="3"/>
            </EnumType>

            <EntityContainer Name="TheGreatModelContainer" p5:UseClrTypes="true" xmlns:p5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation"   >
                    <EntitySet EntityType="ODataMetaDataGenerator.MyObject" Name="MyObjects"/>
            </EntityContainer>

        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

---

The exact source of the error is in `breeze.debug.js at line 8597 - constructor of DataProperty`.

There the defaultValue has to be set and in my case it tries to get the default value from the property dataType.
The dataType at this point looks the following:

```
{
    name: "Undefined",
    defaultValue: undefined
}
```

This happens due to a failure in `line 7091 - var dataType = DataType.fromEdmDataType(csdlProperty.type);`

because csdlProperty looks like:

```
{
    name: "BehaviourType",
    nullable: undefined
    type: "ODataMetaDataGenerator.BehaviourType"
}
```

Which of course is not an Edm-Type and thus fails.. Should the underlying type of the enum be used here?